# Is there a way to get rid of rust from the metal plate/frame to which headlights are attached, behind the front bumper of '03 Infinti g35?

Tags: repair, rust, infiniti, g35

I just bought an 2003 Infiniti g35. During a minor repair, i noticed that the frame to which the headlights are joined/fixed (not know what it is called), just above the wheel, is rusted very badly. It seems quite delicate. And most probably the rust has spread further inside. Is there a way to fix that area? If it is, what should i ask for? 
The car works fine but has a lot of rusted spots. Should I try to get them fixed? Or they are not worth the pain?

Also, is it worthy to get the underside of car rust-proofed?

Comment: Yes if you want to keep it and look after it, but it depends on how much you want to spend...

Comment: I do want to keep it. But I don't know who should I aapproach to get it repaired.

Comment: A person with the skills that you can trust ... what else do you expect me to tell you?

Comment: This is the first time I bought a car. I don't think I know any mechanic that I can "trust".

Comment: Alright, I just wanted to know if it can be fixed. Apparently it can be. So, I should get it fixed then.

Comment: Related: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/12187/12030 . Depends on how bad the rust is, but it can be prohibitively expensive to truly fix.  Surface rust can be cleaned and painted, but if the structure of the metal is harmed, it can get very expensive very fast.  Of course the cost of repair will vary with the quality of the results.

Comment: It is not on the outside. From outside it seems fime. But the rust is present more to the inside of the car. And i don't think it is easily accessible.